# htaccess file not working for wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to add a new rule in the htaccess file that will allow input of `other` instead of the actual name of the page which is `notify`. But I can't seem to get it to work.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^other$ notify [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Also tried something like:

```
RewriteRule ^other$ index.php/notify [QSA]
```

and this:

```
RewriteRule ^other$ /index.php/notify [QSA]
```

Also tried adding the rules from wordpress itself (inside the admin_init section of a plugin) and then refresh the rules by going to the permalinks settings, choosing post name and then save but no luck either. Upon checking htaccess file it produced a rule similar to the above one:

```
add_rewrite_rule('other', 'index.php/notify', 'bottom');
```

I've verified that I can override the rules via the htaccess file in the root directory because when I tried to use an actual file in the server `hello.php`

```
RewriteRule ^other$ hello.php [QSA]
```

It works. I just don't know why when I use a wordpress page it doesn't work. It also seems to work when I use the absolute path:

```
RewriteRule ^other$ http://somesite.com/notify [QSA]
```

But this is no good because when I add some arguments to the URL (which is what I will ultimately do) I end up with bad looking URL when I do the above: http://somesite.com/?some_argument=some_value

The current permalink setting in wordpress is set to post name. Any ideas what I have missed?

Comment: Have you tried - `RewriteRule ^other$ /notify` ?

Comment: tried it just now, doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^other/?$ index.php?p=PAGE_ID [QSA]
```

Put the necessary PAGE_ID to redirect to

Comment: What response do you have if you apply this rule?

Comment: I still get the 404 not found on wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Hello may be you can use .htaccess plugin..! to control it from admin panel. I hope this Help you

> http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-htaccess-control/